# What to do before the return in directives of AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was asking myself, what things can you put in ***before*** the `return` statement, when defining directives in AngularJS?

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDir', function() {
    // What can you do here?
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            // do things
        }
    };
});
```

So some general questions are:

**1. What can you do there? 
 
2. What can only happen there? 

3. What shouldn't be done in there?**

---

One thing I found useful, is that you can store variables or functions in there which you can then use in the definition of the directive, but I would like to hear some other suggestions.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives, comments about "InjectingFunction".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since no one else has answered yet... as I mentioned in the comments, the [Understanding Directives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives) wiki page has some useful information.

The first time the directive is encountered, Angular will run the directive function once.  So whatever you put here will only be executed one time (or maybe zero times if the directive is not used anywhere in your app.)  So, if something can be shared between *all* directive instances, you can put that here:  functions, directive-global variables, one-time initialization, etc.

Note that any functions that you put here will be rather limited.  They won't have access to the scope or element or attributes – unless you pass them in as arguments.  For that reason, functions that are used by the compile or link functions are often put inside the compile or link functions because then they'll have access to the scope, element, and attributes due to JavaScript closures.  The two example directives on the [Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) page do this.